How to get current time in seconds in my service override.conf file
I am using some third-party service where I need to write override.conf.
in override.conf I need the current time in seconds but am not able to get it.
I have written the below override file
/etc/systemd/system/myservice.service.d/override.conf
# ----------------- override.conf -----------------
[Unit]
Wants=another.service

[Service]
StandardOutput=journal
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c 'date +%s > /tmp/service_start_time'
ExecStartPost=/bin/bash -c 'date +%s > /tmp/service_stop_time'
ExecStartPost=/bin/bash -c 'START=$(/tmp/service_start_time); STOP=$(/tmp/service_stop_time) ELAPSED_TIME=$(( START - STOP )); echo $SPEND_TIME>/tmp/service_spend_time'
ExecStartPost= do something with $SPEND_TIME time here
ExecStop=
ExecStop=/opt/operation/bin/myservice stop 2>&1
# ---------------------------------------------------

but when i cat /tmp/service_start_time
the output is:
/bin/sh
so I tried a lot but didn't get success.
the simple question is how to get the current time in override.conf

[so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

STOP=$(/tmp/service_stop_time) should be STOP=$(</tmp/service_stop_time) if you want to set the variable to the file contents. Your syntax tries to execute /tmp/service_stop_time as a program.

Is SPEND_TIME supposed to be ELAPSED_TIME (or vice-versa)?
